# How to capture command response during OpenSSH on cmd using QTP

Tags: vbscript, cmd, qtp, openssh, hp-uft

I am doing openSSH through cmd to connect linux system. I can see command response on cmd console but not able to capture command response using QTP. I need responses to be used in my runtime script. I do not want to use "GetVisibleText" method.

Comment: Show a sample of what code you are talking about. Also tell the world about why you 'do not want to use "GetVisibleText" method'. And define what command response you want to capture -- that written on standard output? What does this have to do with QTP (I don´t doubt it has, but tell us about what you are trying to achieve)?

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked on openSSH but you can try redirecting the output of cmd prompt to a text file and read contents of the text file

Example:

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
return = WshShell.Run("cmd /c java > ""C:\temp\aa.txt"" 2>&1 ")

Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\aa.txt", 1)
If file.AtEndOfLine<> true Then
            text = file.ReadAll
            MsgBox text
        else
            MsgBox "file is empty"
End If
file.Close
```